# realloc(): invalid next size while using Dynamic Stack implementation

Tags: arrays, c, stack, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

So, I was learning Stack Data Structure and implemented the dynamic array based stack, I am a little new to Dynamic Array Allocation. Everytime my stack gets filled I am calling the `doubleStack()` function in which I am doubling the the size of array using `realloc()`. Error is on `realloc()` when the capacity is 4. The error is **realloc(): invalid next size**

```
void doubleStack(struct stack* s){
   s->capacity*=2;
   s->arr=realloc(s->arr,s->capacity);
}
```

My whole Code just for the reference:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

struct stack{
    int top;
    int capacity;
    int *arr;
};

struct stack* CreateStack(){
    struct stack *s=(struct stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
    if(!s){
        return NULL;
    }
    s->top=-1;
    s->capacity=1;
    s->arr=(int*)malloc(s->capacity * sizeof(int));
    if(!s->arr) return NULL;
    return s;
}
void doubleStack(struct stack* s){
    s->capacity*=2;
    s->arr=realloc(s->arr,s->capacity);
}
int isEmptyStack(struct stack *s){
    return s->top==-1;
}

int isFullStack(struct stack *s){
    return s->top==s->capacity-1;
}

void push(struct stack *s,int data){
    if(isFullStack(s)){
        doubleStack(s);
        
    }
       s->arr[++s->top]=data;
    
}

int pop(struct stack *s){
    if(isEmptyStack(s)){
        return INT_MIN;
    }
    else{
        return s->arr[s->top--];
    }
}

void deleteStack(struct stack *s){
    if(s)
        if(s->arr){
            free(s->arr);
        }
        free(s);
}
int main(){
    struct stack *s= CreateStack();
    push(s,0);
    push(s,1);
    printf("%d\n",pop(s));
    push(s,3);
    push(s,6);
    push(s,6);
    push(s,9);
    push(s,6);
    push(s,6);
    push(s,9);
    push(s,6);
    push(s,6);
    push(s,9);
    printf("%d\n",pop(s));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `s->arr=realloc(s->arr,s->capacity);` -> `s->arr=realloc(s->arr,s->capacity * sizeof (int));` Does this help?

Comment: Your `doubleStack()` function is playing with fire because you don't check that the reallocation succeeds.  Using the `oldptr = realloc(oldptr, newsize)` idiom risks leaking memory on allocation failure.  You should use `newptr = realloc(oldptr, newsize); if (newptr == NULL) { /* Handle failure */ } oldptr = newptr;`.  You might want to avoid changing the old size until you know that the allocation was successful, too.

Comment: `if(!s->arr) return NULL;` You forgot to do `free(s);`

Comment: @babon Yess, It works and yeah it makes sense too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for the suggestion will keep in mind.

Comment: @Gerhardh Yeah thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

Building this code with `gcc -g -fsanitize=address` and running yields:

```
==7673==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000000054 at pc 0x00000040155f bp 0x7ffe19b3fff0 sp 0x7ffe19b3ffe8
WRITE of size 4 at 0x602000000054 thread T0
    #0 0x40155e in push /tmp/t.c:39
    #1 0x4016d8 in main /tmp/t.c:62
    #2 0x7f560a4ff55f in __libc_start_call_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x2d55f)
    #3 0x7f560a4ff60b in __libc_start_main_impl (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x2d60b)
    #4 0x401114 in _start (/tmp/a.out+0x401114)

0x602000000054 is located 2 bytes to the right of 2-byte region [0x602000000050,0x602000000052)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f560a78ac98 in __interceptor_realloc (/lib64/libasan.so.6+0xaec98)
    #1 0x401374 in doubleStack /tmp/t.c:24
    #2 0x4014ac in push /tmp/t.c:36
    #3 0x4016d8 in main /tmp/t.c:62
    #4 0x7f560a4ff55f in __libc_start_call_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x2d55f)
```

As babon commented, you need this:

```
    s->arr=realloc(s->arr,s->capacity * sizeof(int));
```

After doing so, `invalid next size` will be gone, and only memory leaks will remain:

```
==7680==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 16 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7fad9095291f in __interceptor_malloc (/lib64/libasan.so.6+0xae91f)
    #1 0x4011e7 in CreateStack /tmp/t.c:12
    #2 0x4016b9 in main /tmp/t.c:60
    #3 0x7fad906c755f in __libc_start_call_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x2d55f)

Indirect leak of 64 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7fad90952c98 in __interceptor_realloc (/lib64/libasan.so.6+0xaec98)
    #1 0x40137b in doubleStack /tmp/t.c:24
    #2 0x4014b3 in push /tmp/t.c:36
    #3 0x401784 in main /tmp/t.c:71
    #4 0x7fad906c755f in __libc_start_call_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x2d55f)
```

To fix the leak, you need to actually call `deleteStack()` at the end of `main()`.

Comment: Yess, It works. But can you suggest something to prevent memory leaks too?

Comment: @AyushRaghuvanshi I've updated the answer.

Comment: ohkay thank you